# parsing SEO friendly url without htaccess or mode_rewrite

Tags: php, url, seo

Can anyone suggest a method in php or a function for parsingSEO friendly urls that doesn't involve htaccess or mod_rewrite?  Examples would be awesome.

```
http://url.org/file.php/test/test2#3
```

This returns: Array ( scheme] => http [host] => url.org [path] => /file.php/test/test2 [fragment] => 3 ) /file.php/test/test2

How would I separate out the /file.php/test/test2 section?  I guess test and test2 would be arguments.

EDIT:

@Martijn - I did figure out what your suggested before getting the notification about your answer.  Thanks btw.  Is this considered an ok method?

```
$url = 'http://url.org/file.php/arg1/arg2#3';
$test = parse_url($url);
echo "host: $test[host] <br>";
echo "path: $test[path] <br>";
echo "frag: $test[fragment] <br>";
$path = explode("/", trim($test[path]));
echo "1: $path[1] <br>";
echo "2: $path[2] <br>";
echo "3: $path[3] <br>";
echo "4: $path[4] <br>";
```

Comment: Drop Apache and use the similar feature provided by other web servers?

Comment: If you don't have access to htaccess or mod rewrite you should consider switching hosts. If that's not the reason for this question, could you explain why you want to do that?

Comment: I have editted my answer in reply to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use explode to get the parts from your array:

```
$path = trim($array['path'], "/"); // trim the path of slashes
$path = explode("/", $path);
unset($path[0]); // the first one is the file, the others are sections of the url
```

If you really want to make it zerobased again, add this as last line:

```
$patch = array_values($path);
```

---

**In response to your edit:**
You want to make this as flexible as you can, so no fixed coding based on a max of 5 items. Although you probably will never exceed that, just don't pin yourself to it, just overhead you dont need.

If you have a pages system like this:

```
id parent  name                url
1   -1      Foo                 foo
2    1      Bar, child of Foo   bar-child-of-foo
```

Make a recursive function. Pass the array to a function which takes the first section to find a root item

```
SELECT * FROM pages WHERE parent=-1 AND url=$path[0]
```

That query will return an id, use that in the parent column with the next value of the array. Unset each found value of the $path array. In the end, you will have an array with the remaining parts.

To sketch an example:

```
function GetFullPath(&$path, $parent=-1){
    $path = "/"; // start with a slash
    // Make the query for childs of this item
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE parent=".$parent." AND url=".current($path)." LIMIT 1");
    // If any rows exists, append more of the url via recursiveness:
    if($result->num_rows!==0){
        // Remove the first part so if we go one deeper we start with the next value
        $path = array_slice($patch,1); // remove first value
        $fetch = $result->fetch_assoc();
        // Use the fetched value to go deeper, find a child with the current item as parent
        $path.= GetFullPath($path, $fetch['parent']);
    }
    // Return the result. if nothing is found at all, the result will be "/", probs home
    return $path;
}

echo GetFullPath($path); // I pass it by reference, any alterations in the function happen to the variable outside the scope aswell
```

This is a draft, I did not test this, but you get the idea im trying to sketch. You can use the same method to get the ID of the page you are at. Just keep passing the variable back up again c

One of these days im getting the hang of recursiveness ^^.
*Edit again: Oops, that turned out to be quite some code.*